# Can you use a variable as an order of operations?

Tags: php, html, variables, syntax, calculator

I'm working on a basic calculator script using html and php. The idea is to enter in two numbers and pick the operator you want to use.

HTML Code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Calculator</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<h3>Calculator</h3>

<form action="calc.php" method="get">

<p><input name="num1" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8">

<select name="calc">
    <option value="+">+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="*">*</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
</select>

<input name="num2" type="text" size="8" maxlength="8"></p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Calculate"></p>

</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<?
    $num1=$_GET['num1'];
    $num2=$_GET['num2'];
    $calc=$_GET['calc'];

    $result = $num1 $calc $num2;

    echo "$result";
?>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Is this ($result = $num1 $calc $num2;) logical or completely wrong? Are there any alternatives? Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that functionality isnt available in PHP.

You'll need a `switch` statement or conditional of some kind:

```
switch($calc)
{
    case "+":
        return $num1 + $num2;
        break;
    case "-":
        return $num1 - $num2;
        break;
}
```

**Note:** someone will inevitably note that the `break` expressions aren't strictly necesarry if you're using `return`'s on every case but they're in the specification and IDE's sometimes pick up their absence.

Comment: As per leemo code, that's the right way to do it. Using any form of eval or similar is a gross assumption that input is correct and not malicious. Furthermode, you should probably strip anything that doesn't look like a digit, +ve or -ve, or a decimal point, from the input numbers. that would be, use a regex to only allow those legal input characters and nothing else.

Comment: This worked for me but I'm not getting any output. How can I echo the result using this?

Comment: @ScooterParr I was assuming you were going to dump the above code into a function. You simply change the `return`'s to `echo`'s

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$num1=$_GET['num1']; // get value 1 from your form
$num2=$_GET['num2'];// get value 2 from your form
$calc=$_GET['calc']; // get operator from your form
$operators = array(
'+' => 'bcadd',
'-' => 'bcsub',
'*' => 'bcmul',
'/' => 'bcdiv'
);
echo $operators[$calc]($num1, $num2);
?>
```

See more at [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php)

Comment: I have not tested it, but you may or may not run into some url encoding issues with this. Other than that, it's a good answer.